# How to decode the image data

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. In that I get the images information from the server.IU got the each image data like below.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIYAAACGCAMAAAAvpwKjAA...
```

So my problem is how to get the image from this data.please tell me how to solve this one.

Comment: We really don't need all that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSData *imageData = **//Image Data**;
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Your data is not a valid image data

Answer (score 0):

This is NSData, you have to use this to get image.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
```